# enable advanced search in master

Tags: sharepoint-designer

Is there any way, to enable advanced search in default search box.
for the advanced search I am using, sharepoint hyperlink

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" id="HyperLink1" CssClass="adsrch">Advanced Search</asp:HyperLink>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't Enable/Disable Advanced Search.

It's only a WebPart.
If you have a WebPart Zone, you can add Advanced Search WebPart( Search category) and it will work if Search Service is running in your farm.

Comment: beside this, I have language pack install,
can we make a single link,
'EN' or 'AR',once you click on it, it will switch to languages.

Comment: Please open a new question for this :)